# Ruby string sub without regex back references

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I'm trying to do a simple string sub in Ruby.

The second argument to sub() is a long piece of minified JavaScript which has regular expressions contained in it. Back references in the regex in this string seem to be effecting the result of sub, because the replaced string (i.e., the first argument) is appearing in the output string.

Example:

```
input = "string <!--tooreplace--> is here"
output = input.sub("<!--tooreplace-->", "\&")
```

I want the output to be:

```
"string \& is here"
```

Not:

```
"string & is here"
```

or if escaping the regex

```
"string <!--tooreplace--> is here"
```

Basically, I want some way of doing a string sub that has no regex consequences at all - just a simple string replace.

Comment: Can you create a small example the demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 6):

To avoid having to figure out how to escape the replacement string, use [`Regex.escape`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Regexp/escape/class). It's handy when replacements are complicated, or dealing with it is an unnecessary pain. A little helper on String is nice too.

```
input.sub("<!--toreplace-->", Regexp.escape('\&'))
```

Comment: That fixes the example, but it seems to cause problems elsewhere. Eg, if you change the 2nd arg to '\&,O=/\s*([\s\+\~>])\s*/g' then the output looks like 'string \&,O=/\s\*\(\[\s\\~>\]\)\s\*/g is here' with loads of extra things escaped.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use block notation to make it simpler (as opposed to Regexp.escape):

```
=> puts input.sub("<!--tooreplace-->") {'\&'}
string \& is here
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful - especially as it applies to other uses (for example, reading a file and using the file contents as the string for replacement) in which escaping is simply not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes and escape the backslash:

```
output = input.sub("<!--tooreplace-->", '\\\&') #=> "string \\& is here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since `'\\&'` (that is, `\` followed by `&`) is being interpreted as a special regex statement, it stands to reason that you need to escape the backslash. In fact, this works:

```
>> puts 'abc'.sub 'b', '\\\\&'
a\&c
```

Note that `\\\\&` represents the literal string `\\&`.